# React/Ant Design fix back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have an app written in React and Ant Design pro.
I have a logout method:

```
  logout() {
  removeToken();
  if (window.location.pathname !== '/user/login' && !redirect) {
    history.replace('/user/login')
  }
},
```

After clicking logout button it successfully redirect to /user/login page but when I click on 'back button' in Chrome it goes back to the application dashboard ('/') but it shouldn't.
Im wondering how to make back button works properly, so it always after clicking back button redirects to /user/login page.

Comment: if it goes to the dashboard, it means the code did not log you out in the first place, if it did, follow the comment below

Comment: You have to add authentication condition on your roots file (App.js) that when token removed it will (or not) show /dashboard.